# show a div when atleast two checkboxes has checked

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox

I need to show a div when  two or more check boxes are checked.
I Have a working JSfiddle. The JavaScript goes

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){
                 $('#checkobox').change(function(){
                   alert($('input:checked').size())
                       if($('input:checked').size() > 1){
                        $('div').show();   
                   }
                   else {
                        $('div').hide()   
                   }
                 });
            </script>
```

The html content

```
         <input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
         <input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
         <input type="checkbox" id="one"></input>
         <div style="display: none;">At least 2 are checked</div>
```

I have another script in same page to select all, is it conflict this two checkbox selecting.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#checkall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
                    if(this.checked) { // check select status
                        $('.checkbox1').each(function() { 
                            this.checked = true;                
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('.checkbox1').each(function() { 
                            this.checked = false;                    
                        });         
                    }
                });
            });
       </script>
```

This code works fine, but not in local host and server.
Show your skills...and give me a solution..thanks

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/jkR2h/` this is the working jsfiddle

Comment: check for any errors in console?

Comment: Please make sure you include jquery library in your head part in localhose

Comment: You should probably make a stacksnippet or add your code in the question.

Comment: just go the above mentioned jsfiddle link and copy it to ur local host with some library...tell me if it works..thanks guys

Comment: @SaleemNFS I dont think people are going to do that. You have been asked, politely, to improve your answer by adding the code to the question, or making a stacksnippet. This helps by making the question more useful to people with a similar problem, and makes it much more likely that you will get an answer. As it stands the question is likely to get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your script inside `$(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){` so that it will bind change event to checkboxes when whole DOM is ready. Also make sure that you have included jQuery library in your HTML but before your script.

EDIT : - to remove conflict with another script, you can put `class="one"` for your checkboxes (I have removed `id="one"` as you cannot use same id for multiple elements) as shown below and change the script accordingly

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="one"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="one"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="one"></input>
<div style="display: none;">At least 2 are checked</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox].one').change(function(){
    alert($('input[type=checkbox].one:checked').size())
        if($('input[type=checkbox].one:checked').size() > 1){
         $("div").show();   
    }
    else {
         $('div').hide()   
    }
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jkR2h/40/)**

Comment: i have another script to check all . is this conflict for checking two or more checkbox? still it not working

Comment: could you please share the other script .

Comment: yes..added it...kindly look at that...after adding your code when am selecting all it will alert the size .so it works only for selecting all script..beacause in your code `$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function()`  is same as the select all checkbox..

Comment: actually i am using datatable and the checkoboxes are from the loop, the all checkoboxes displays in same page of select all option page(1st page).
how can i call that checkobox id or class in this page(1st page).
thankssssss

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in jsfiddle and share the link